# Manual formatting in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I´m stuck in this scenario. I have a text file that has many lines like this:

```
123450,ADN,,2785,"1,576,000,000.06",TEXT TEST TEXT,,
999999,NSU,,1234,"-1,576,000,000.06",TEXT TEST TEXT TEST,,
790834,CHI,,5678,"2,345,000,000.01","TEXT TEST (TEXT), TEST",,
893472,JAP,,0123,"-2,345,000,000.01","TILL THERE (ALMOST), UH",,
093289,CRU,,6489,"424,000,000.00",TEST TEXT UB,,
```

And I need to do formatting to see the results like this:

- First position needs to have 14 characters with leading zeroes (fixed width)
- Second position need to put together the 3 letters + 4 numbers with leading zeroes (12 chars fixed width)
- print + sign to separate
- then the value without `,`, `.`, and `"` (18 characters fixed width)
  and the text without `,`, `.`, and `"`:

  ```
  00000000123450ADN000002785+000000157600000006TEXT TEST TEXT
  00000000230634NSU000001234+000000157600000006TEXT TEST TEXT TEST
  00000000232014CHI000005678+000000234500000001TEXT TEST (TEXT) TEST
  00000000230634JAP000000123+000000234500000001TILL THERE (ALMOST) UH
  00000000232015CRU000006489+000000042400000000TEST TEXT UB
  ```

I am trying to do it using [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table), but I am not able to manipulate and specify the leading zeroes and fixed width. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this (replace the file paths with your own):

```
$infile = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\input.txt" -Delimiter "," -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
$outfile = "C:\Temp\output.txt"
if(Test-Path $outfile){ Remove-Item $outfile } # Remove any existing output files

foreach($line in $infile) # Loop through lines
{
    $outline = "" # Empty output line
    $outline =
        ($line.1).PadLeft(14,"0") +
        $line.2 +
        ($line.4).PadLeft(12,"0") +
        "+" +
        ($line.5).Replace(",","").Replace(".","").Replace("-","").PadLeft(18,"0") +
        ($line.6).Replace(",","").Replace(".","")

    $outline | Out-File $outfile -Append # Write to output file
}
```

The key to the output spacing is to use padleft and replace the characters you don't want.

Comment: Awesome Morgb! Your answer explains why I was not able to work it out, I tried using the Import-CSV but thought it should be a CSV file and not a .txt. It worked perfectly. Thanks for sharing the knowledge, it helped me a bunch. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You format it the same way you build any complex formatted string: One field at a time. PowerShell can use .NET string format specifiers with the `-f` operator.

Standard format specifiers such as `{N:DX}` can format the number fields (once they're converted to `[int]`).  We first do some string handling on the text fields.

```
$rawInput = @"
123450,ADN,,2785,"1,576,000,000.06",TEXT TEST TEXT,,
999999,NSU,,1234,"-1,576,000,000.06",TEXT TEST TEXT TEST,,
790834,CHI,,5678,"2,345,000,000.01","TEXT TEST (TEXT), TEST",,
893472,JAP,,0123,"-2,345,000,000.01","TILL THERE (ALMOST), UH",,
093289,CRU,,6489,"424,000,000.00",TEST TEXT UB,,
"@

$items = ConvertFrom-Csv $rawInput -Header 'num1','alpha1','blank1','num2','num3string','text','blank2','blank3'

$items | foreach {
  # Remove unwanted characters from num3string field and pad left with zeroes
  # Note this also discards the `-` character, which was not specified, but it is
  # necessary to get the desired output.
  $numString = ($_.num3string -replace '\.|\,|\-','').PadLeft(18, '0')

  # Strip unwanted characters from the text field as well
  $textField = $_.text -replace '\.|\,|\"',''

  # Build the string using .NET-style format strings.
  # To leading-pad the numbers, use {N:DX} which means
  # format argument N as a decimal int X chars wide
  '{0:D14}{1}{2:D9},{3}{4}' -f (
      [int]$_.num1,
      $_.alpha1,
      [int]$_.num2,
      $numString,
      $textField
    )
} | Out-File 'out.txt' # Send output to a file
```

You don't specify in your question how you are reading the data into PowerShell. Obviously, if you've already imported the CSV into a PowerShell variable, you should use your own fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan! This is really it, the way I´m reading the file is using the $Data = Get-Content. Will do some tests tomorrow to incorporate this solution in my script. Was trying to select the content using select command but not working either, your solution made it very clear. Thanks for the comments, they help to understand it. Well done.

Comment: @user6436367 You can use `Import-Csv` like in morgb's answer to read from a file into a CSV variable.  Use `ConvertFrom-Csv` to read from a multiline string (such as in the code above) or a list of strings (such as the output of `Get-Content`).  Both will give you a list of structured objects, which is much easier to work with, as you can see. :)

Comment: Also note that the `-Header` parameter to either cmdlet is needed if there is no header line in the file.  Usually in a normal CSV file, the first line is the header that lists the fields used in the rest of the lines.  If your CSV has a header, that will determine the name of the fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan for the detailed explanation, it´s much more clear now. :)